# a simple thing to ask regards to update an instance with 'params'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I am using **Rails v2.3.2**.

If :

```
params[:car]={"name"=>"mycar", "brand"=>"toyota"}
```

I tried to udpate a `@car` instance by:

```
@car.update_attributes(params[:car])
```

but the `@car` is not updated.

**Why I can not update like this?** Do I must update the `@car` by specify each filed like following:

```
@car.update_attributes(:name=>params[:car][:name], :brand=>params[:car][:brand])
```

instead of update with the `params[:car]` as a whole like:

```
@car.update_attributes(params[:car])
```

Anyone can explain to me?

**P.S.** the `params` is:

```
{"commit"=>"Save", "authenticity_token"=>"w/d2uI/2tK9vSZvtF9oQDjY5iBPL8fji33IZcpm9cY0=", "_method"=>"put", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"4", "controller"=>"cars", "car"=>{"name"=>"mycar", "brand"=>"toyota"}
```

Comment: basicly what your doing is right, could you please post thet params[] hash?!

Comment: @ davidb, I updated my post. Please have a look.

Comment: usually that means that @car has a validation error ? Does `@car.errors` show anything ?

Comment: @ davidb, the @car also contain the Rails made  :created_at, :updated_at fields, could that be a problem?

Comment: @ davidb, yes, it looks like a validation error, though the @errors={} is empty. But after I change the value of :name during update, it get updated successfully. The interesting thing is why there is no validation message show when update, but it shows when create new instance with invalid value...

Comment: @davidb, can you make your comment as an answer so that I can accept your answer, because you pointed out the reason of the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No, never update an object like this:

```
@car.update_attributes(:name=>params[:car][:name], :brand=>params[:car][:brand])
```

This is wrong. This would only be useful if you only want to update these attributes.

Always use this instead:

```
@car.update_attributes(params[:car])
```

Assuming your params don't have anything more in them besides `name` and `brand` then these two statements are identical.

What you're doing in the first one is that you're building this hash:

```
{ :name => "mycar", :brand => "Toyota" }
```

And in the second one, you're passing through a hash that is basically identical, with the only difference being the object's id.

As for why the object is not saving, try calling `update_attributes` and then call `.errors` on the object after that and that will return any validation errors that were encountered when saving.